# How does the "client.on()" function really work?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I've been using Javascript to code discord bots lately, and most bots have a pretty standard program, something like this:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("message", (message) => {
    //code to react to message
});

client.login("BOT-TOKEN");
```

Now, I'm not understanding how the `client.on()` works at a fundamental level. I'm able to understand that `message` in `(message)` represents the message object that's provided by discord to the client, but what does `"message"` stand for? It seems to be another parameter within the `client.on()` function, but what is that for? I've tried looking at the discord.js Documentation, but couldn't find the info about `client.on()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That parameter is a string, showing what types of event to listen for.

Basically, when the Discord client receives a message, it will execute the function that is the second parameter. There are actually many other strings for different events. For example, if you use `"ready"` instead of message, it will call the function in the second parameter when the client is ready to start sending and receiving messages. You can see a list of these strings at their documentation: http://discordjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs_client.html#events

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I noticed that a `"messageDelete"` is sent whenever a message is deleted, so does this mean I can have a command ti react to deleted messages by using `client.on("messageDelete", () => {//code here});`?

Comment: Yes, definitely

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

on is used to add a callback function that's going to be executed when the event is triggered. for more refer this doc
https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/the-nodejs-event-emitter/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33617046)